# number of different binary trees that can be formed?

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree

binary tree, where each node has at most two child nodes, child nodes may contain references to their parents.

`we do not differentiate the nodes and all nodes are considered identical.` How can we find the number of different binary trees that can be formed with N identical nodes.

eg: if 3 nodes then 5 diff trees
    if 7 nodes then 429 trees

Comment: Hint: Google for "Catalan numbers"

Comment: @Bart Kiers, I think, the question is not about Catalan numbers, because there is no catalan number which equals to `5` (see the OPs sample). or I think so for `429`

Comment: @Saeed, you're wrong. The first few Catalan numbers are: [1, 1, 2, 5, 14, 42, 132, 429, 1430, ...](http://oeis.org/A000108)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, if you really want to understand this, instead of just getting (or experimenting to find) the answer, you can check out "The Art of Computer Programming", Volume 4, Fascicle 4: [Generating all trees](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/fasc4a.ps.gz).

Answer (score 1):

recursion is your friend!

pseudo-code:

```
numOfTrees(n):
  return trees(n).size();

trees(n):
  if (n==1)
    return new list of single node;

  big_trees = new empty list;

  for (small_tree : trees(n-1))
    for (big_tree : addSingleNode(tree))
      big_trees.insert(big_tree);

  return big_trees;

addSingleNode(tree):
  trees = new empty list;

  for (leaf : getLeaves(tree)) {
    trees.insert(tree.clone().addLeftChild(leaf, node));
    trees.insert(tree.clone().addRightChild(leaf, node));
  }

  return trees;
```

getLeaves() is implementation dependant, if you have a linked list with all leaves, then it will be quick, otherwise you might have to traverse the tree checking for leaves (which is O(n) in_order).

not very memory efficient, but it solves the problem by simple recursion, where at every stage i take the trees and go over all the leaves and add my new node in every possible way.

Comment: I didn't think enough about correctness of your recursion algorithm, but as I can see you try constructive way, but if the number of trees are exponential with `n`, your algorithm is not good choice.

Answer (score 1):

(2n)!/[(n+1)!*n!]

have a look at:

http://www.theory.csc.uvic.ca/~cos/inf/tree/BinaryTrees.html

Comment: Thanks. This is the formula for catalan.